# Syntax error in condition

Tags: python, boolean, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error for the `=` sign prior to the `65` integer literal. Can somebody please help me figure out how to fix the syntax error?

```
age = int(input('Age? '))
if age <= 15 or >= 65:
  print('Discount Applied.')
else:
  print('Discount ineligible.')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `age` again in your condition:

```
age = int(input('Age? '))
if age <= 15 or age >= 65:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
age = int(input('Age? '))
if 15 < age < 65:
     print('Discount ineligible.')
else:
     print('Discount Applied.')
```

Comment: I have changed the if and else conditions as well just to give OP possible options

Comment: Please clarify that in your answer so that anyone who adopts your suggestion doesn't introduce a bug into their code.

Comment: It is self explanatory. I have just reversed the condition.

Comment: It may not be obvious to somebody who ready your answer quickly and doesn't realize that you've switched the condition _and_ the statement bodies. Why not just say that in your question to be safe?